# Repositioning Relative Divs Resize

Tags: html, css

I am trying to layout a row with many relative positioned Divs.
They are all inline-block elements with different heights.
You can see it here in my codepen:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/Cyrill/pen/akQRxm)

How can I avoid the white space between Nr. 1 (red) and Nr. 5 (black) if the window gets smaller and the DIVS get rearranged in the second row?
So that Nr. 5 sticks directly under Nr.1?

Is this possible with CSS?

Thank you for any help!

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="drag" id="item_1">1</div>
<div class="drag" id="item_2">2</div>
<div class="drag" id="item_3">3</div>
<div class="drag" id="item_4">4</div>
<div class="drag" id="item_5">5</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.drag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#item_1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#item_2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

#item_3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
}

#item_4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#item_5 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put in the drag class this code

```
body
    {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    .drag 
    {
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
```

floating the divs to each other is very usefull ...